# WPF Polygon to bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, polygon

How can I convert the wpf polygon shape as a bitmap image?  I am trying to send as Visual parameter to change as bitmap, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there any other way to convert the WPF polygon to bitmap?

am using like below

```
RenderTargetBitmap RTbmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)yellowPolygon.Width, (int)yellowPolygon.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
RTbmap.Render(yellowPolygon); 
image1.Source = RTbmap;
```

Comment: This link describes the same problem, unfortunately I couldn't get it working. I still get a blank image, if I try it the way he does it. Maybe you have more luck:
http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/150676.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Change `Width` and `Height` to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.

Line, polygon etc which are defined via points have undefined width and height. When rendering to a bitmap you should use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.

I just tried this in a sample project and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
(int)image1.ActualWidth
```

and

```
(int)image1.ActualHeight
```